# How can one pre-check a checkbox after a specific date and time?

Tags: php, forms, validation, date, checkbox

I have a form with a late fee that I want to be added automatically after a specific date and time.

The script we use requires a checkbox and an amount field for each item on the form. So the late fee has a checkbox, and when checked, $25 appears in the accompanying field. This fee is then added to other fees on the form.

I would like to hide the Late Fee checkbox with css (but leave its accompanying text), and have the $25 late fee appear in the amount field after a specific date/time.

I already have a hidden field collecting the current date, if that is useful for the solution. (")

I hope I have explained this well enough. I will clarify if asked to do so.

I have searched for quite some time, trying to find an answer to no avail. Hoping an angel out there could assist me. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just put it in with PHP at that specific time?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're trying to do.

```
<?php

# Get a DateTime obj for the late date (christmas in this case)
$lateDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", "25-12-2013", new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));

# The date now
$now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));

# Get a boolean for whether it's late or not
$isLate = ($now->getTimestamp() > $lateDate->getTimestamp());
?>

<? if ($isLate): ?>
You're late!!!
<? endif; ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="lateFee" value="25" <?=($isLate ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, how about:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$lateFee = null;
$hide = null;
if($today > $cutOffDate){
    $lateFee = 'value="25.00"';
    $hide = 'hide';
}
echo '<input type="number" step="any" name="lateFee" ',$lateFee,'>';
echo '<input type = "checkbox" name="lateFeeCheckbox" class="',$hide,'">';
```

In your css you can use it hide to hide any input with the "hide" class